# How to install `python-dev` (deb file) without root

Tags: linux, python, deb

I'm using python on a Linux cluster (without root access) and want to use the numpy module. After downloading numpy from [Numerical Python](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=liquidtelecom), extracting and trying to install it with:

```
python setup.py install --home=/home/"myusername"/"myfolder"
```

(as I have successfully done with previous python modules), I get the error:

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

So to try and locally install `python-dev`, I downloaded the `.deb` from [python2.7-dev_2.7.10-2_amd64.deb](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/python2.7-dev/download) and extracted it in "myfolder" as described in http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/01/28/how-to-extract-rpm-or-deb-packages/, however this did not solve the previous error and I cannot find any more relevant help.

I do not have access to `apt-get` or `dpkg`.

Comment: Have you tried asking the system administrator to install the packages you require? It seems to me it would be a more sensible way forward than trying to pick packages apart and install them in non-standard places

Comment: I would if it was easiest, however I'm using a few different clusters, most of them without much installed and am trying to make my own setup across them as consistent as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [download the source](https://www.python.org/downloads/) for python-2.7.10 from the python.org site.
Once you extract `.tar.xz` archive you will find the Include directory that contains the missing missing header files.

You can tell `python setup.py ...` to look in this directory as well by setting

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/your/extracted/Python-2.7.10/Include
```

Comment: This worked, I just have to from now on make sure I'm using my python installation and not the system wide one.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is a very old question and my answer will be (slightly) off-topic as I am addressing only the problem of installing *Python* packages as an ordinary user.

The solution for this particular use case is to use virtual environments . See the [Python documentation of the `venv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for details.

As to the generic problem of installing Debian packages without root or sudo rights, I am still looking for an answer myself...

Comment: 6 years later comes with a lot of experience: virtual environments, pip with `--user` argument, or local conda/miniconda installations is absolutely the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment @roaima made; however, you can always use `alien` to convert the .deb to a .tgz and then untar it.

So, after making alien you'd use `alien -tc package.deb`.

Comment: I can't use alien either.

Comment: You can `alien` it on another system, upload the .tgz file to server and use it.